# Como realizar um crud com firebase?

Tags: firebase

Li um artigo sobre Firebase, achei maravilhoso o que na teoria é capaz de realizar.
Gostaria de sua ajuda pois quero criar um CRUD, só que sempre utilizei Mysql.
Pelo pouco que entendi utiliza JSON ( NO-sql).

Como posso criar isto manualmente em NO-sql no arquivo JSON? Queria Montar uma tabela assim no CRUD, exemplo:

```
ID Nome_Produto   Unidades
0  carro             1   
1  carro2            3  
2  carro3            5
```

Se podem me orientar algúm material de leitura para entender mais sobre Firebase (banco de dados) seria ótimo, agradeço desde já!!!

Comment: Tem uma sequência de videos com explicações excelentes sobre isso: Clique [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noB98K6A0TY "Getting Started with the Firebase Realtime Database on the Web, Part 1")! E a documentação também [aqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start "Firebase Database ")!

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/?hl=pt-br A própria documentação do firebase ensina tudo de maneira bem fácil e intuitiva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, em primeiro lugar, você deve esquecer a lógica de trabalho em bancos SQL e passar a interpretar as instâncias das classes em que trabalha diretamente, essa é a logica de bancos de dados não relacionais do tipo documento (ex: Firebase, MongoDB, MariaDB, etc...).

Quando se trabalha com esse tipo de base de dados, os objetos são instanciados diretamente, conforme os seus elementos. No caso do firebase (que é sua escolha) ele não permite trabalhar diretamente com arrays dentro dos objetos, ao invés disso ele permite definir as keys para um objeto pai de forma ordenada. O resultado seria algo desse tipo:

```
{
  "carros": {
    1: { "nome": "carro", "unidades": 1 },
    2: { "nome": "carro2", "unidades": 3 },
    3: { "nome": "carro3", "unidades": 5 },
  }
}
```

Com essa estrutura, você não precisa mais manter o "id" da tabela dentro do objeto pois ele é somente um index relacional e deixa de ser uma referência lógica. Se caso seja necessário utilizar, o firebase permite que, na consulta você diga a ele que envie também a chave `$key`para seu objeto, que será identificada diretamente como se fosse o seu "id".

Aconselho a começar a estudar No-SQL porque daqui pra frente é o futuro em relação ao armazenamento de dados em questão ao custo/benefício. Mesmo bancos de dados bem utilizados e robustos como o Oracle e o MS SQLServer não são comparáveis a bancos No-SQL quando se tem o tratamento massivo de dados e uma grande massa de conexões simultâneas.